# How to find a number of prime numbers in a specific row of multidimensional array in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have following multidimensional array written in C:

```
int arr[3][4] = {
{ 1,  2,  3,  4 },
{ 5,  6,  7,  8 },
{ 9, 10, 11, 12 }
};
int rows = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
int cols = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr[0][0]);
```

What I need is to ask user for specific row and find how many prime numbers are in this row:

```
void findRowPrime(int rownumber, int start, int end){
printf("enter the row number to find prime numbers"); 
int primerow = scanf(&primerow);
}
```

I found ways how to find it for a usual array, but I didn't find how to do it for multidimensional.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. A 2D array can be treated like an array of 1D arrays, so just look through each of the 'column' elements of `arr[row]`.

Comment: Why is `findRowPrime()` reading inputs? Matrix is already there. And what are `start` & `end` arguments?

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and show how you do it for a one-dimensional array, then it will be easy to show you how to extend it for a two-dimensional array.
The code `int primerow = scanf(&primerow);` is wrong. The function needs a format string, and putting both the converted number and the return value, which shows if the conversion(s) was/were successful, into the same variable does not make sense. Read the [documentation of `scanf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Comment: "I found ways how to find it for a usual array" --> post those ways.